# Next.js: CSS Module is not included in the React Component

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, typescript, next.js

I tried to include and apply the style from a CSS module to a React component. However, the style is never applied, and the CSS is also never included.

This is the code I have until now:

**./components/Toolbar.tsx**

```tsx
import styles from "./Toolbar.module.css";

export default function Toolbar({title = "Social Media App"}) {
    return (
        <div className={styles.toolbarContainer}>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**./components/Toolbar.module.css**

```css
.toolbar-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: grey;
}
```

**./app/layout.tsx**

```tsx
import type {Metadata} from 'next'
import {Inter} from 'next/font/google'
import React from "react";
import Toolbar from "@/components/Toolbar";
import Homepage from "@/app/page";
const inter = Inter({subsets: ['latin']})

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'Some Social Media App',
    description: 'Some new kind of social media outlet'
}

export default function RootLayout({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>
        <Toolbar title="Homepage" />
        {children}</body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

**./app/page.tsx**

```tsx
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Homepage() {
    return (
        <>
            <p>Welcome to the homepage!</p>
            <Link href={"/dashboard"}>Dashboard</Link>
        </>
    )
}
```

Why does the CSS from the `Toolbar.module.css` not get included in the displayed page?

I tried putting the Toolbar in different locations and in different files. I also tried including the toolbar in the `layout.tsx` file itself. But that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st.: Because the hyphen is valid in classnames in CSS files, but in JavaScript assigned to subtraction operation.

2nd: The selector in the CSS file and the reference in the React component must be the same!

This is working:

In React component:
`<div className={styles.toolbarContainer}>`

In CSS file:
`.toolbarContainer{ ... }`

---

This is NOT working (both are valid but values mismatches):

In React component:
`<div className={styles.toolbarContainer}>` **VALID**

In CSS file:
`.toolbar-container{ ... }` **VALID**

---

This is also NOT working (explained in 1st point above):

In React component:
`<div className={styles.toolbar-container}>` **NOT VALID**

In CSS file:
`.toolbar-container{ ... }` **VALID**